# How to delete an account created through ./acme-account-creation-tool

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-secrets-manager

I have created an account as follows

```
./acme-account-creation-tool -e email -o my-letsencrypt -d letsencrypt-prod
```

How can I delete the account created by above command?

Answer (score -1):

Let's Encrypt does not support removing or unregistring an account. Accounts are not unique, though and so you can simply register a new account.

Reference: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/unregister-account/16856